# Injecting $scope into typescript controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am writing my first typescript controller and am having a little bit of an issue understanding how to use $scope so that I can refer to elements within different code blocks.  Here is the relevant code :

```
    module app.controllers {

        class TeamsController implements app.domain.Team {

            //properties
            teamId: number;
            teamName: string;
            coach: app.domain.Coach;
            division: app.domain.Division;
            cheerleaderImage: string;
            coachImage: string;
            headerImage: string;
            logoImage: string;

            divisions: app.domain.Division[];
            coaches: app.domain.Coach[];
            teams: app.domain.Team[];

            selectedTeam: app.domain.Team;
            teamToBeUpdated: app.domain.Team;

            httpService: ng.IHttpService;

            static $inject = ['dataAccessService', '$http', '$scope'];

            //constructor
            constructor(private dataAccessService: app.common.DataAccessService, $http: ng.IHttpService, $scope: ng.IScope) {

                this.teams = [];
                this.divisions = [];
                this.coaches = [];

                this.httpService = $http;

                var teamResource = dataAccessService.getTeamResource();
                var divisionResource = dataAccessService.getDivisionResource();
                var coachResource = dataAccessService.getCoachResource();

                teamResource.query((data: app.domain.Team[]) => {
                    this.teams = data;
                });

                divisionResource.query((data: app.domain.Division[]) => {
                    this.divisions = data;
                });

                coachResource.query((data: app.domain.Coach[]) => {
                    this.coaches = data;
                });

                this.selectedTeam =
                    new app.domain.Team(0, "", new app.domain.Coach(0, ""), new app.domain.Division(0, ""), "", "", "", "");
                this.teamToBeUpdated =
                    new app.domain.Team(0, "", new app.domain.Coach(0, ""), new app.domain.Division(0, ""), "", "", "", "");
            }

    addUpdateTeam(): void {

                if (this.teamToBeUpdated.teamId === 0) {

                    //vm.isBusy = true;
                    //vm.errorMessage = "";

                    //post, pass teamToBeUpdated object
                    this.httpService.post('http://localhost:33201/api/Teams/Add', this.teamToBeUpdated)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            //success
                            this.teams.push(response.data);
                            this.teams.sort(function (a, b) {
                                if (a.teamName.toLowerCase() < b.teamName.toLowerCase()) return -1;
                                if (a.teamName.toLowerCase() > b.teamName.toLowerCase()) return 1;
                                return 0;
                            });
                            this.teamToBeUpdated =
                                new app.domain.Team(0, "", new app.domain.Coach(0, ""), new app.domain.Division(0, ""), "", "", "", ""); //clear form
                        }, function (error) {
                            //failure
                            //vm.errorMessage = "Failed to save new team: " + error;
                        })
                        .finally(function () {
                            //vm.isBusy = false;
                        });
                }
            }
}

    //registration with module must be declared after class
    angular.module("app")
        .controller("teamsController", ['dataAccessService', '$http', '$scope', TeamsController]);
}
```

Where I am using `this` above, I would like to replace it with `$scope`, but when I try to do that I get the error '{propertyname} does not exist on type IScope'.

Can anybody advise on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an interface that extends ng.IScope with the properties you need.

```js
interface TeamsScope extends ng.IScope {
  teams: string[]
}
```

And use that instead of ng.IScope in the constructor.

```js
constructor(private dataAccessService: app.common.DataAccessService, $http: ng.IHttpService, $scope: TeamsScope) {
```

All properties defined in a class can only be accessed trough **this**.

For example you can access **$scope** in one of the class methods like this:

```
this.$scope
```

In order to keep the same lexical scope inside the handler given to the $http service you can use an **arrow function**.

```
this.httpService.post('http://localhost:33201/api/Teams/Add', this.teamToBeUpdated)
                        .then((response) => { this.teams = resonse.data});
```

You can find more about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) here.

Comment: Thanks....this works in the constructor, but how do I gain access to $scope in the method addUpdateTeam above?

Comment: Regarding your reply, I tried that but I want to get access to the outer scope from inside this.httpService.post code block, in which case I cannot use this, if I am right?

Comment: that's because **this** changes when that function is called. try sending an arrow function to the **then** instead of a normal function.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the syntax your are referring to?

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!