# How to write an interface for controller factory return type

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.8

I'm trying to get rid of as many references to 'any' from my app as possible. Is it possible to get rid of this one - what interface can I write for my controller factory?

> ```
> return (controller) as any;
> ```

```
module TsApp.Home {
    "use strict";

    export interface IBlogEntries {
        blogEntries: Common.BlogEntry[];
    }

    interface IBaHomeController {
        $scope: IBlogEntries;
        baBlogEntriesService: Common.IBlogEntries;
        $http: ng.IHttpService;
    }

    class BaHomeController {
        $scope: IBlogEntries;
        baBlogEntriesService: Common.IBlogEntries;
        $http: ng.IHttpService;

        public static factory(): IBaHomeController[] {
            const controller = (log: ng.ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, blogEntriesService: Common.IBlogEntries, http: ng.IHttpService
            ): IBaHomeController => {
                return new BaHomeController(log, $scope, blogEntriesService, http);
            };

            controller.$inject = ["$log", "$scope", "BaBlogEntriesService", "$http"];

            return (controller) as any; //#2
        }

        constructor(private $log: ng.ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, private bBaBlogEntriesService: Common.IBlogEntries,
            private http: ng.IHttpService) {
            const defer = bBaBlogEntriesService.getAsync();
            defer.then(response => {
                $scope.blogEntries = response.data;
                $log.debug("blog entries");
            });
        }
    }

    angular
        .module("Main")
        .controller("BaHomeController", BaHomeController.factory()); //#1
}
```

I thought that "return (controller) as IBaHomeController[];" would work, but I get this error:

> Neither type '(log: ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, blogEntriesService: IBlogEntries, http: IHttpService) =>...' nor type 'IBaHomeController[]' is assignable to the other.
>     Property 'push' is missing in type '(log: ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, blogEntriesService: IBlogEntries, http: IHttpService) =>...'.

Since that is the method's defined return type, I thought that it would work. Which leads me to be believe that I need to change the method's return type?

**EDIT**: If there is a simpler way to inject dependencies, that would work for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

it is complaining because return type of factory method is an Array of `IBaHomeController` and you are trying to return a single instance of `BaHomeController` and trying to cast it as an Array.

If you return a single instnace it will work.

```
  public static factory(): IBaHomeController {
        const controller = (log: ng.ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, blogEntriesService: Common.IBlogEntries, http: ng.IHttpService
        ): IBaHomeController => {
            return new BaHomeController(log, $scope, blogEntriesService, http);
        };

        controller.$inject = ["$log", "$scope", "BaBlogEntriesService", "$http"];

        return (controller) as IBaHomeController;
    }
```

Not sure if solves your purpose.

Comment: I tried your change but I get two errors. 1) The angular controller method creates this error: TS2345 Argument of type 'IBaHomeController' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'IBaHomeController'. BaHomeController.ts 43. Also, the cast to IBaHomeController results in an error: TS2345 Argument of type 'IBaHomeController' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'IBaHomeController'. BaHomeController.ts 43

Comment: are you getting error in your factory or where you are trying to use it?

Comment: I added a comment //#1 to indicate where the first error occurs, and //#2 for the second

Comment: can you make the return type of factory as IBaHomeController instead of IBaHomeController[] at #2 make any as IBaHomeController, At #1 use **[** BaHomeController.factory() **]** see factory is wrapped in square brackets to indicate array.

Comment: Now at #2 I receive the error: TS2352 Neither type '($log: ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, blogEntriesService: IBlogEntries, http: IHttpService) =...' nor type 'IBaHomeController' is assignable to the other.
  Property '$log' is missing in type '($log: ILogService, $scope: IBlogEntries, blogEntriesService: IBlogEntries, http: IHttpService) =...'. I don't understand because $log exists right in the error message and the signatures are exactly the same

Comment: Ofcourse it should complain, i should had seen it earlier, controller is a function and when you are trying to cast it to IBaHomeController the types dont match. you have to get instances of all the injectable and while returning have to provide controller(...all injectables) as  IBaHomeController.

Comment: Hmm that does get it to compile, but doesn't work. I can get an instance of log using const $log = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$log") as ng.ILogService;, but how do I get an instance of $scope, $http, and my custom service?

Comment: cant you do the same for scope and http, for scope you might have to extend IScope for reference see [Injecting $scope into typescript controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695660/injecting-scope-into-typescript-controller)

Comment: tx! i can drop my factory method and use the approach in the link you provided for controllers. but have the same issue for directives that lack controllers. if you update your answer as such i can mark as answer and post a new question about directives

Comment: Please update the question, asking how to inject dependencies or create a new question for the same.